# Passing array of structures to function by value in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, structure

I want to pass an array of three structures to a function that sorts the three  numbers stored in the array of structures, but do not want to change the actual values ​​, as arrays are passed by reference , there's my problem , any ideas accept thanks :)

Here is my code for review:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
typedef struct
{
    int digito;
} numbers;

void  sort(numbers tabla[], int nro);
void enternums(numbers  tabla[], int nro);

int main()
{
    static numbers enter[N];
    int i, j, tmp;
    enternums(enter, N);
    printf("Data before entering the function...\n\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", enter[i].digito);
    }
    sort(enter, N);

    printf("After entering data function....\n\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", enter[i].digito);
    }
    return 0;
}

void enternums(numbers tabla[], int nro)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < nro ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a digit for the position %d:  ", i);
        scanf("%d", &tabla[i].digito);
    }
}

void sort(numbers tabla[N], int nro)
{
    int i, j, tmp;
    for (i = 1 ; i < nro ; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        tmp = tabla[i].digito;
        while ((j > 0) && (tmp < tabla[j - 1].digito))
        {
            tabla[j].digito = tabla[j - 1].digito;
            j--;
        }
        tabla[j].digito = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write the code in such a way that it's so hard to read, you can do it like I did. And certainly arrays are not passed by reference.

Comment: I don't really understand what you actually want, and `scanf("%d", &tabla[i].digito);` is a potential bug in your code since you don't check for the returned value, i.e. success or failure of `scanf()`.

Comment: You could make a copy of the passed array and sort the copy

Comment: @bpgeck Which would make sens if you return the array, otherwise it's just an intentional memory leak!

Comment: @iharob He doesn't have to do a deep copy. He can just store it on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the array as a pointer<sup>1</sup> to it's first element, has the advantage that you can actually pass another array to store the new values

```
void sort(const numbers *const tabla, numbers *resultado, int nro)
{
    int i, j, tmp;
    for (i = 1 ; i < nro ; i++)
        resultado[i].digito = tabla[i].digito;
    for (i = 1 ; i < nro ; i++)
    {
        tmp = resultado[i].digito;
        for (j = i ; (j > 0) && (tmp < resultado[j - 1].digito) ; --j)
            resultado[j].digito = resultado[j - 1].digito;
        resultado[j].digito = tmp;
    }
}
```

Making the `while` loop a `for` loop instead, it would make your code clearer.

And to use this

```
int main()
{
    static numbers enter[N];
    static numbers ordenado[N];
    int i, j, tmp;
    enternums(enter, N);
    printf("Data before entering the function...\n\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", enter[i].digito);
    }
    sort(enter, ordenado, N);

    printf("After entering data function....\n\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ordenado[i].digito);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, make your code safer by checking for possible errors, for example

```
scanf("%d", &tabla[i].digito);
```

should be

```
if (scanf("%d", &tabla[i].digito) != 1)
    Oops_there_is_a_problem_dont_use_this_value_maybe_ask_again();
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Which happens automatically, it's not passed by reference it's converted to a pointer</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass arrays by value unless they are contained in a `struct`.

You can use:

```
typedef struct MyStrutArray
{
   numbers  enter[N];
} MyStructArray;
```

and then use:

```
void  sort(MyStructArray array);
```